# Правильное создание корзины на PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, redis, memcached, cart

бьюсь уже долгое время как правильно сделать корзину на php.

По задумке должно быть так: если пользователь авторизован, то корзина должна сохраняться в базу и должна быть доступна при следующем входе, если гость то корзина на сессиях.

Так вот, вроде ничего сложного, но слишком много запросов к базе это плохо для авторизованного пользователя и хочется сразу сделать качественно и красиво, по-правильному. Думал сделать через паттерн компоновщик где у меня отдельные классы обрабатывают по отдельности каждый вид сохранения в корзину: SessionCart, DbCart, SessionDbCart и тд. В таком случае для гостя вызывается SessionCart, а для авторизованного пользователя SessionDbCart, чтобы корзина сохранялась и в сессии и в базу. Но как тогда сделать синхронизацию сессии и базы при авторизации пользователя? И тогда получается тоже много запросов на базу. Думал так: чтоб при закрытии пользователем страницы корзина из сессии отправлялась на базу.

В общем мыслей очень много и решил попросить совета у более опытных людей. Думал также над вариантами с memcached и redis, но в них очень слаб и не до конца понимаю область их применения. Изначально "вдохновлялся" корзиной с озона.

Comment: и где там у вас "слишком много запросов к базе" то?

Comment: Так если пользователей на сайте например больше 100 и все активно его пользуют добавляя и удаляя товары из корзины то запросов на базу на сервере уже получается порядочно. Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Не следует оптимизировать с самого начала, добейтесь сначала результата, а затем оптимизируйте его. Подход правильный, мы тоже в Symfony такой же использовали, и конверсия товаров с сотнями параметров происходила достаточно быстро.

Comment: Обычно при авторизации сессия сохраняется. Поэтому нужно отследить момент авторизации, и если сразу после авторизации обнаруживаем корзину в сессии, то добавляем её в базу.

Comment: Виктор, а если после авторизации и сохранения корзины в базу пользователь далее работает с корзиной, то товары добавлять и в сессию и в базу или только в базу?

Comment: Дэниэл, спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: а другие страницы кроме корзины они что без запросов работают? Чем таким особенным корзина будет выделяться из остальной работы?

Comment: Теран, то есть в принципе способ описанный мною в вопросе рабочий и не сильно косячный?